# How to not return a value of 0 when data does not exist in table, SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have two tables, table A and B, and I am counting the number of occurences of a data type from table A,

```
    ENAME       SALES
    ---------- ----------
    Wilson          0
    Fox             1
    Wang            2
    Green           1
    Fox             0
    Phillips        2
    Loftus          0
    Smith           2
    Smith           3
    Wolf            2
    Jones           1
    Liu             0
```

Where when the sales count is 0, the ename does not exist in table B at all.

How would I go about removing the 0 count? I'm trying to get the return to look like this:

```
    ENAME       SALES
    ---------- ----------
    Wilson          
    Fox             1
    Wang            2
    Green           1
    Fox             
    Phillips        2
    Loftus          
    Smith           2
    Smith           3
    Wolf            2
    Jones           1
    Liu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `case`, another `nullif()`:

```
select ename, nullif(sales, 0) as sales
from t;
```

If this is an aggregation query:

```
select ename, nullif(count(*), 0) as sales
from t
group by ename;
```